# Adding the same product image path to multiple products through csv import issue

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, image, csv, importexport

I am trying to add products by duplicating them in a CSV file.

It seems to work fine but when I update the product image path with the same path to multiple products it doesn't seem to update.

When I export again and look at the data it has reverted to it original state.

What is the problem here...?

Comment: "It seems to work fine" *What seems to fine? The import?*

Comment: Your image needs to be in media/import/catalog/product with same subpath and filename as in media/catalog/product after importing. After importing Magento moves these images to /catalog/product so if you ran same import second time it will not find the images so no images will be set.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* when Magento imports data, the images are moved, so when you try to use the same image two times, the second time the images is not found.

Just a guess.